# Display PDF using base64 data with NativeScript nativescript-pdf-view plugin

Tags: nativescript

Hi I am having trouble displaying base64 data using the `nativescript-pdf-view` plugin in my Nativescript app.

This works fine:

```
<PDFView *ngIf="(expense.receipt_filetype=='pdf')" src="https://www.domedomain.com/somefile.pdf"></PDFView>
```

but this is showing blank:

```
<PDFView *ngIf="(expense.receipt_filetype=='pdf')" src="data:application/pdf;base64,{{expense.receipt_data}}"></PDFView>
```

Any ideas why the base64 data is not displaying?

Note this works fine for images:

```
<Image *ngIf="(expense.receipt_filetype=='jpg')" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{expense.receipt_data}}" width="100%" height="100%" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
```

Thanks.

Comment: PDFView do not support loading the file as Base64 string, you will have either use a local file or remote one. You might be able to load the base64 string into WebView using Chrome client, but you will have to do it natively but I'm not very sure but it worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj - I will direct users to the website to view PDFs (for now)